# Add more YAML files to Bolt Theme

Tags: symfony, yaml, silex, bolt-cms

By default Bolt themes allow you to have one YAML file (config.yml) for access in theme files. I use a large amount of arrays for use in my themes, and for organizational purposes wanted to see if there's a way I could add more YAML files for use in Bolt.

What would be the best method for adding additional YAML files/arrays for my theme to use?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly straightforward. Try something like the following in the Extension class (that extends BaseExtension)....

```
// Load another config
if ($this->isConfigValid('another.yml', true)) {
    $this->loadConfigFile('another.yml');
}
```